# parse space separated text file using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

Can someone please help me with this parsing using awk?
Sorry I don't have any code
My input space separated text file ( the file has a few more fields in the item lines)

```
category is fruits


item id  8837878
item id  8837879
item id  8837880
item id  8837881
item id  8837882
item id  8837883
item id  8837884
item id  8837885
item id  8837886
item id  8837887
item id  8837888
item id  8837889


category is veg

item id  8837890
item id  8837891
item id  8837892
item id  8837893
item id  8837894
item id  8837895
item id  8837896
item id  8837897
```

Required tab separated output file

```
fruits item id  8837878
fruits item id  8837879
fruits item id  8837880
fruits item id  8837881
fruits item id  8837882
fruits item id  8837883
fruits item id  8837884
fruits item id  8837885
fruits item id  8837886
fruits item id  8837887
fruits item id  8837888
fruits item id  8837889
veg item id  8837890
veg item id  8837891
veg item id  8837892
.....
```

Comment: Looking at this question, I want to press `Ctrl-V`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^category/{c=$3}/^item/{print c,$0}' file
fruits item id  8837878
fruits item id  8837879
fruits item id  8837880
fruits item id  8837881
fruits item id  8837882
fruits item id  8837883
fruits item id  8837884
fruits item id  8837885
fruits item id  8837886
fruits item id  8837887
fruits item id  8837888
fruits item id  8837889
veg item id  8837890
veg item id  8837891
veg item id  8837892
veg item id  8837893
veg item id  8837894
veg item id  8837895
veg item id  8837896
veg item id  8837897
```

To format the output exactly how you need it you can use `printf`:

```
$ awk '/^category/{c=$3}/^item/{printf "%s %s %s %d\n",c,$1,$2,$3}' file
```

So by tab separated output maybe you mean:

```
$ awk '/^category/{c=$3}/^item/{printf "%s %s %s\t%d\n",c,$1,$2,$3}' file
```

Comment: +1. neat solution. It would be better to add the `tab separated output' part.

Comment: I missed that part @Kent thanks for pointing it out. Added `printf` to my answer.

Comment: gawk "/^category/{c=$3}/^item/{print c,$0}" file works great. I had to replace ' with " because I am running this using Gawk for Windows - GnuWin32. However the code with printf gives syntax error when I replace ' with "

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the nuances of quoting on windows. A quick fix would be to put the script in a file. So put `/^category/{c=$3}/^item/{printf "%s %s %s\t%d\n",c,$1,$2,$3}` in `script.awk` and run `awk -f script.awk file`.

Comment: Perfect. Works great :)

Comment: with the above code the tab is only on the last field. This seems to work /^category/{c=$3}/^item/{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\n",c,$1,$2,$3}

Comment: @sudo_O the text 'category' has a leading single space.Putting a space before the word does not help. can you please help me get around this problem?

Comment: Just drop the anchor `^` then.

Comment: /^^category/{c=$3}/^item/{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\n",c,$1,$2,$3}  if you mean like this, then it does not work

Comment: I said drop it (that means remove or delete) i.e. `/category/{c=$3}/^item/{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\n",c,$1,$2,$3} `

Answer (score 3):

This is an attempt:

If a line contains "is" in the 2nd field, then we store the category name, print an empty line and continue checking the file.

In the rest of cases, if the 2nd field is "id", we print the line preceded by the category name.

```
$ awk '$2=="is"{c=$3; print ""}$2=="id"{print c,$0}' file

fruits item id  8837878
fruits item id  8837879
fruits item id  8837880
fruits item id  8837881
fruits item id  8837882
fruits item id  8837883
fruits item id  8837884
fruits item id  8837885
fruits item id  8837886
fruits item id  8837887
fruits item id  8837888
fruits item id  8837889

veg item id  8837890
veg item id  8837891
veg item id  8837892
veg item id  8837893
veg item id  8837894
veg item id  8837895
veg item id  8837896
veg item id  8837897
```

Comment: I like the short regex matching but sting comparison would be tighter `awk '$2=="is"{c=$3}$2=="id"{print c,$0}' file` +1.

Comment: Thanks, @sudo_O, I always learn a lot from your comments and answers! Updated acordingly.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. also the empty line as separator. it makes the output look good, although OP didn't say if he needs it.